# PHPUnit: Does assertThat() increment assertion count?

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I have a custom assertion that isn't incrementing the assertion counter. I run >1900 assertions on this code, and the final assertion count is zero. I know that it is running the assertion because I can make it fail. But whether it fails or not, it claims that zero assertions were run.

Here is the definition for my custom assertion:

```
protected function assertMethodResult($class_name, $method_name, $arguments, $expected, $message='')
{
    $condition = new MyConstraint; // proprietary code; extension of PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint
    self::assertThat(array('class_name'=>$class_name, 'method_name'=>$method_name, 'arguments'=>$arguments, 'expected'=>$expected), $condition, $message);
}
```

The [PHPUnit manual page](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertThat) for `assertThat()` doesn't indicate whether or not it increments the assertion count, and a search for further documentation turned up nothing.

What do I need to do to make this custom assertion count as one assertion and increment the assertion count properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Constraint` class implements `Countable`. The required `count` method will return the number of assertions that will be added to the counter when evaluating the Constraint:

https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/5.7.26/src/Framework/Assert.php#L2056

Your constraint `count` method should return at least `1` in order for the assertions to be counted. Check if it's returning `0` instead.